# How do I remove the border that appears when map area is selected in Leaflet map

Tags: angular, leaflet, geojson, angular-leaflet-directive

I created a leaflet map that overlays map tiles using a GeoJson file. When I click on a area that I have overlaid a ugly black border appears as below.

I also have used leaflet tooltip to bind a tooltip to each feature area with the below code

`layer.bindTooltip(this.returnTooltip(feature))`

The black border appears only when I bind the tooltip. When the above code is commented out the black border doesn't appear when an area is selected.

[image]

I can't find where this border is getting added from, I just want to completely remove it.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/447502/

Comment: @IvanSanchez your solution works, issue is I am using angular and the CSS doesn't seem to be applied into the map. Any way I can solve this?

Answer (score 4):

This is called outline and i.e. used for highlighting things without affecting the layout or for accessibility reasons.

You can use this to remove it everywhere:

```
*,
*:focus,
*:hover {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes this works, my issue now is getting the CSS to apply in the map component. What I type in the CSS file does not seem to get applied. Any way to get around this?

Comment: @Ovindu can't you inspect that layer and look for the corresponding css selector?

Comment: I can do that, but adding the CSS to the layer is the issue I'm having